# ZF2 getting doctrine service inside bootstrap zfcUser extendet event

Tags: events, doctrine, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I have been extending the ZfcUser I got the new fields working, and they are getting added to the db via doctrine2 no problem there.
But now i need to add a links between the user and a payment table and a special Role system.
Im trying to put this into the Event but i cant get a hold on the doctrine service.
My onBootstrap looks like this.

```
public function onBootstrap( MVCEvent $e )
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $em           = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
    $em->attach(
        'ZfcUser\Form\RegisterFilter',
        'init',
        function( $e )
        {
            $filter = $e->getTarget();

            // do your form filtering here 
            new Register\Filter($filter);

        }
    );

    // custom form fields

    $em->attach(
        'ZfcUser\Form\Register',
        'init',
        function($e)
        {
            /* @var $form \ZfcUser\Form\Register */
            $form = $e->getTarget();
            new Register\Form($form);
        }
    );

    // here's the storage bit

    $zfcServiceEvents = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('zfcuser_user_service')->getEventManager();
    $doctrineObjectManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    var_dump($e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('zfcuser_user_service')->getEventManager()->getEvents()); 
    $zfcServiceEvents->attach('register', function($e){
        /* @var $user \User\Entity\User */
        //$form = $e->getParam('form');
        //print_r($form);
        //echo get_class($e);
        new Register\Storage($e);
        break;
    });

    // you can even do stuff after it stores           
    $zfcServiceEvents->attach('register.post', function($e) {
        /*$user = $e->getParam('user');*/
    });
}
```

Form and filter works, but i cant get access to docrtine service from within the anonymous event function. How do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're doing this in `onBootstrap()` the `MvcEvent` has everything you need. You just need to fetch the entity manager and `use` it in your anonymous function

```
public function onBootstrap( MVCEvent $e )
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $em           = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
    // fetch the entity manager
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $entityManager = $sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    $em->attach(
        'ZfcUser\Form\RegisterFilter',
        'init',
        // use the entity manager in your function
        function( $e ) use ($entityManager);
        {
            $filter = $e->getTarget();

            // variable $entityManager is now available in this scope
            // so we could for example inject it into the filter like so
            new Register\Filter($filter, $entityManager);                

        }
    );
```

I'm assuming the entity manager was the doctrine service you were referring to, but it's the same methodology to `use` other services in the scope of your anonymous functions.